# Disable product data section for specific users only

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce backend, I know that you can remove the Product tabs globally with some code on **`functions.php`**.

But I only want to remove for the user back end. I'm using a multivendor plugin.

How do I do it?

My code:

```
function remove_tab($tabs){
    unset($tabs['inventory']); // it is to remove inventory tab
    //unset($tabs['advanced']); // it is to remove advanced tab
    //unset($tabs['linked_product']); // it is to remove linked_product tab
    //unset($tabs['attribute']); // it is to remove attribute tab
    //unset($tabs['variations']); // it is to remove variations tab
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_tab', 10, 1);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that your vendors have a **custom user role**, you can achieve this targeting this specific user role in your function, this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'verdors_remove_tab', 10, 1);
function verdors_remove_tab($tabs){

    // Set HERE your targeted user role SLUG
    $target_user_role = 'multivendor';

    // Get current user (object)
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_roles = $current_user->roles; // current user roles

    // Unsetting tabs for this specific user role
    if( in_array( $target_user_role, $current_user_roles ) ){
        unset($tabs['inventory']); // it is to remove inventory tab
        //unset($tabs['advanced']); // it is to remove advanced tab
        //unset($tabs['linked_product']); // it is to remove linked_product tab
        //unset($tabs['attribute']); // it is to remove attribute tab
        //unset($tabs['variations']); // it is to remove variations tab
    }
    return($tabs);
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Is that possible to remove attribute tab from Products data and show after the Product Description editor as individual Field and its attributes values ???