# Remove the ability to modify or create inventory in woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce

I have a question, I need to remove only the ability for a role like shop_manager to edit and create inventory in both simple and variable products.

I know that woocommerce does not have this capability specifically, how could I implement something to do this?

I have tried everything but nothing works

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786003/10497022) for simple products? What is _"everything"_  you have tried?